# Android: What is the share dialog class in Facebook SDK 4.x

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the code below to open Facebook share dialog with a Facebook page URL.

The problem is, when I look to the shared post on my wall via Facebook application, I find the post without the shared page cover.

While if I shared the same page via Facebook application on my wall, I find the post with the shared page cover (Which of course is much cooler).

**Is there a missing parameters in the code below?**

**I'm using Facebook SDK 4.1.2**

```
    FacebookDialog shareDialog = new ShareDialog(mMainActivity);
    if (ShareDialog.canShow(ShareLinkContent.class))
    {
        ShareLinkContent linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                .setContentUrl(Uri.parse(aFacebookPageURL))
                .build();


        shareDialog.show(linkContent);
    }
```

Edit 1:

using .setImageUrl(Uri.parse(aPageCoverURL))

You can see the difference between the upper half (shared via Facebook app for mobile) and the bottom half (shared via my application).

[image]

**Edit 2: How can I use the code below to share a Facebook page? The code below is not working and no share dialog appears, I don't know if there is a missing parameters or this code is not meant to share pages, but I'm trying.**

```
    ShareOpenGraphObject object = new ShareOpenGraphObject.Builder()
            .putString("og:type", "page")
            .putString("og:title", aTitle)
            .putString("og:url", aURL)
            .build();

    // Create an action
    ShareOpenGraphAction action = new ShareOpenGraphAction.Builder()
            .setActionType(null)
            .putObject("page", object)
            .build();

    ShareOpenGraphContent content = new ShareOpenGraphContent.Builder()
            .setPreviewPropertyName("page")
            .setAction(action)
            .build();

    ShareDialog.show(mMainActivity, content);
```

Comment: If anyone has a solution or suggestion it would be appreciated, my question & bounty are not restricted to credible and/or official sources. Thank you all.

Answer (score 2):

From the Facebook [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android#links):

> **Links**
>
> When people share links from your app to Facebook, it includes
>   attributes that show up in the post:
>
> - a **contentURL**, the link to be shared
> - a **contentTitle** that represents the title of the content in the link
> - a **imageURL**, the URL of thumbnail image that will appear on the post
> - a **contentDescription** of the content, usually 2-4 sentences

If you want to display the image you should use [setImageUrl(@Nullable final Uri imageUrl)](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/facebook/src/com/facebook/share/model/ShareLinkContent.java#L139-L142):

```
ShareLinkContent linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                .setContentUrl(Uri.parse(aFacebookPageURL))
                .setImageUrl(Uri.parse(imageUrl))
                .build();
```

This is a share from SDK:

[image]

This is a share directly from the app:

[image]

Comment: Smart solution, but for sorry its result is not the same as sharing via Facebook application.

Comment: I just tried and seems the same to me. I edited the answer with the screenshots of a share from SDK and from the app. Can you post the screenshots of your results?

Comment: I just added the screenshot that shows the difference of the result.

Comment: I looked thorough into your screenshot, you have shared a post, but what I'm sharing is a page. Could you plz try sharing a page and see if the results are the same.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think that `ShareLinkContent` is the correct method to share a page like the app. In fact the "advanced card" can be obtained only if you press `Share` directly from the Facebook page. If you press `Copy Link` instead of `Share`, and manually share the copied link you can see that the card is the same obtained when the url is shared from the SDK.

Comment: I understood all what you said except about "advanced card", what is it?

Comment: Got it, so what could be the method used to obtain and share an advanced card?

Comment: Any more suggestions, it would be really appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: Facebook provide only 4 type of share from the SDK right now :`ShareLinkContent`, `SharePhotoContent`, `ShareVideoContent` and `ShareOpenGraphContent`. The first is the one you already know and it's not working as expected. The second and the third is not what you looking for. Maybe the fourth could be the right one, but I tried to do some research and I didn't find anything related to your problem. Unfortunately I can't be to more help.

Comment: You've helped a lot, and I can't thank you enough for that :) I made an edit with your suggestion ShareOpenGraphContent but I can't get it to work, any more suggestion or example?