# How to implement Facebook App Link in Android with example

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to post on Facebook from my Android application and this post function as App Link? Where if someone using Facebook application tapped on this post it will be directed to G.P. to install my app, and if it's installed it will open my app with enough data to view this post in my app activity?

So far I couldn't find an example that shows how to create an App Link object, and how to include data in this object to be retrieved later from intent -> extras, and I'm totally confused how to implement it in Android.

For example, from my application I want to share an http://youtube.com/xxxxx link in a post on Facebook, how to create the App Link using Facebook App Link host feature?

Edit 1:

I need to understand something about app linking, do I create an app link for each post will be posted from my application, or app link is created once to represent my application?

***Edit 2:***

**How to get my app name to be in Blue as Instagram and clicking on it opens my application or go to my Google Play to install if not installed**

[image: How to get my app name to be in Blue as Instagram and clicking on it opens my application or go to my]

*Edit 3:*

**This is the code I use to share, but I don't get my application name a "clickable blue link" as Instagram as in the picture:**

```
    ShareDialog shareDialog = new ShareDialog(mMainActivity);

    if (ShareDialog.canShow(ShareLinkContent.class))
    {
        ShareLinkContent linkContent;
        if(aURL == null)
        {
            linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder().build();
        }
        else
        {
            linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                    .setContentUrl(Uri.parse(aURL))
                    .build();
        }

        shareDialog.show(linkContent);
    }
```

**Shall I make a specific changes in my application settings page on Facebook dashboard?**

Comment: Normally, if you share a youtube link, it will not go to your app, since it wouldn't make sense. If you share your own url (from a domain that you own), then you can add app links meta tags, and then it can open your app.

Comment: @MingLi What if I - The user - want to share a FB page (page's link) from my app, is it possible to implement App Link? so when other FB users taps on the shared FB page post my application will open and preview the page, and if it's not installed they will be directed to GP.

Comment: The only way I see this would work is if you had your own URL space that wrapped the FB urls, and put app links in there.

Comment: @MingLi I think I need to understand more the App Link perspective from FB point of view, because for sorry I didn't understand what you just said, I thought there is a GraphRequest to send it the FB page link + My application package name and it returns me a hosted App Link by FB to be shared, which leads to what I need in the previous comment.

Comment: @MingLi Away of App Link but still in FB area, I hope you have a solution to my question about a problem in sharing FB page (I started a bounty but I still couldn't find a solution): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30356298/android-what-is-the-share-dialog-class-in-facebook-sdk-4-x

Comment: I think you're really thinking about it the wrong way. App Links is a way for you to specify how to get to your app, using a URL that your app owns. If you share a FB url, it's something that *should* be rendered in the FB app (since it, presumably, is the best app to handle it), so it wouldn't go to your app. There's no solution for what you're asking.

Comment: Then why when people share picture as a post from Instagram on FB, and I tap on this picture post, it opens Instagram application with this post? Is it because Instagram owned by FB?

Comment: Are you saying there is no solution to my other question about sharing dialog issue?

Comment: When you share a picture from Instagram, it's an instagram app photo or url. If you shared your own URL (i.e. if your website is foo.com, and you shared a foo.com url), then adding app links tags would have the post go to your app. If you share a facebook.com url, it will not go to your app.

Comment: Thanks, Now I got it ... What about my other question / problem, Anyway of having a solution?

Comment: @MingLi I made an (Edit 2) where I want shared posts via my application to show my application name as a link on mobile, where clicking on it opens my application or go to Google Play to install it, or at least opens a page on my website where I offer the user to download and install my application from Google Play, how to accomplish this?

Comment: How are you sharing on Facebook? If you use the SDK that we publish, and you use the ShareDialog from the SDK, you will automatically get attribution.

Comment: @MingLi I made an Edit 3 with the code I use to share, and yes, I use Facebook SDK share dialog.

Comment: For Android, I believe you need to set the package name, class name, and also toggle the "Single Sign On" button.

Comment: @MingLi Thanks, I already set (package name, class name and enabled "SSO"), what could be missing? Is it because as you told me what is being shared from Instagram comes from Instagram web site, which unlike what is being shared from my application, which is a Facebook page.

Answer (score 2):

You should  use open graph actions for that. first you should create a object . then add an action type. then needs to create a story.  & you have to submit for review process your facebook app.  Normally  share code looks like  this.  read the docs https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/android. & you need to use app links - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks/android

```
// Create an object
ShareOpenGraphObject object = new ShareOpenGraphObject.Builder()
    .putString("og:type", "books.book")
    .putString("og:title", "A Game of Thrones")
    .putString("og:description", "In the frozen wastes to the north of Winterfell, sinister and supernatural forces are mustering.")
    .putString("books:isbn", "0-553-57340-3")
    .build();

// Create an action
ShareOpenGraphAction action = new ShareOpenGraphAction.Builder()
    .setActionType("books.reads")
    .putObject("book", object)
    .build();

// Create the content
ShareOpenGraphContent content = new ShareOpenGraphContent.Builder()
    .setPreviewPropertyName("book")
    .setAction(action)
    .build();

ShareDialog.show(activityOrFragment, content);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to post to facebook(a URL) from your app.
What you can do is:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/plain");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, your_link_here );  
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share via"));
```

This will open up a list of apps where you can share your link which includes facebook app if it is installed. Also have a look at facebook's TOS. You cannot prefill a message as it is against their policy. If you want to share some text along with your URL you will have to use facebook's SDK.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm asking about how to create an App Link Object in Android to be used in Facebook post.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same thing. It turns out that your app should be present on app center (facebook). Then only it will turn into blue link.

In my case, I tried clicking the link, but it landed on a page which said:

> Misconfigured App Sorry, "My app" hasn't been approved for display in
>   App Centre.

So I got the hint from this.