# How to share Facebook App Links to Facebook with preview?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I wanna to implement a share to Facebook function to my app.My app is Android only app.The data that I want to share it to Facebook is text and image that generated by user.So basically when other user click on a "Share" button,will open the `ShareDialog` and post it to their Facebook account.

In order to do this,I successfully get the App Links by using the `Mobile Hosting Api`,I share it to facebook,then click it,it can direct to my app or Play Store.

But now the problem is,the appearance in Facebook of the app link I share is like below

[image: appearance in Facebook]

I try to use `.setImageUrl` , `.setContentDescription` but this is deprecated.

Then I read on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30658269/how-to-implement-facebook-app-link-in-android-with-example) and try to implement my code like below

```
Bitmap image = null;
SharePhoto photo = null;

try {
   URL url = new URL(postImageUrl);
   image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
   } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
   if (image !=null) {
      photo = new SharePhoto.Builder()
                   .setBitmap(image)
                    .setImageUrl(Uri.parse(postImageUrl))
                    .setUserGenerated(true)
                    .build();
    }

    // Create an object
    ShareOpenGraphObject object = new ShareOpenGraphObject.Builder()
          .putString("og:type", "article")
          .putString("og:title", "A Fun Story in Messenglass")
          .putString("og:description", postStatus)
          .build();

     // Create an action
   ShareOpenGraphAction action = new ShareOpenGraphAction.Builder()
   .setActionType("news.reads")
   .putObject("article", object)
   .putPhoto("image",photo)
    .build();

   // Create the content
  ShareOpenGraphContent content = new ShareOpenGraphContent.Builder()
      .setPreviewPropertyName("article")
      .setAction(action)
      .setContentUrl(Uri.parse(Facebook app link)) //here is the app links
      .build();

     shareDialog.show(getActivity(),content);
```

By this Open Graph story,my link share to Facebook have preview,but when I click the link,then not redirect me to my app,but redirect me to App center of Facebook.

I try to submit my app for review for Open Graph story,but my developer App Dashboard dont have any `Open Graph stories` section.

Here is the outlook of the link in Facebook,this is good,but not lead me to my app when clicked,but lead me to App center
[image]

This is Docs I read about the Open Graph Review
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/opengraph/

So what I missing,so I can share my app links that from Mobile Hosting Api to Facebook,with a beautiful preview?Please give me some suggestion

**UPDATE**
After I implement the code above and test in real device,I successfully add the user generated photo and the text to the share dialog.But when I click "Post" in the share dialog,it pop out a progress dialog "Sending" then dismiss,no any other error or something,but I check back Facebook timeline,I dont have the post that shared appear.

**Here is the outlook at the share dialog in my app,but didnt appear in Facebook timeline**
[image]

Can somebody tell me what I missing?What I suppose to do in order to share the applink generate by Mobile Hosting Api,and appear in Facebook timeline with preview photo or description in the post?