# Android: Using Facebook share dialog with action

Tags: facebook

The code below opens Facebook share dialog with action, but the problem that it sets the action in the past "Watched", how can it be set to be "Watching" at the time of posting?

```
    ShareOpenGraphObject object = new ShareOpenGraphObject.Builder()
            .putString("og:type", "video.movie")
            .putString("og:title", aTitle)
            .putString("og:url", aURL)
            .build();

    // Create an action
    ShareOpenGraphAction action = new ShareOpenGraphAction.Builder()
            .setActionType("video.watches")
            .putObject("movie", object)
            ***The period in Seconds before "Watching" turns to be "Watched"***
            .putInt("expires_in", 60)
            .build();

    ShareOpenGraphContent content = new ShareOpenGraphContent.Builder()
            .setPreviewPropertyName("movie")
            .setAction(action)
            .build();

    ShareDialog.show(mMainActivity, content);
```

Comment: The tense in which an action is shown depends on the `expires_time` resp. `expires_in`. Go look at the properties of the action in your app dashboard, when you hover over the question mark next to the properties you’ll see an explicit explanation of this.

Comment: Under what category should I look for action properties? Do you mean I must use (In my Android code above) expires_time & expires_in under ShareOpenGraphObject?

Comment: You should look in the Open Graph section in app dashboard. And yes, you will need to specify one of those properties with your action, to tell Facebook when this action “expires”. As the mentioned explanation says, when you publish a watch action when the user starts watching a movie, you should set it to the movie’s length, so that it will show “watching” for as long as the movie runs, and “watched” after that time.

Comment: Do I need publish_actions permission though I'm using a FB Share dialog and not directly posting to user's timeline?

Comment: Did you need it before? If not, then why would you need it now?

Comment: Because it's first time to use the code above and I wanna make sure, though it's logical not to need it as I"m using FB share dlg. I went to Open Graph -> Action Types -> Watch -> Get code, it shows me "Your app doesn't have an App Namespace set.....", and under Settings tap I haven't set Namespace to anything, what value should I use in Namespace?

Comment: It’s up to you what namespace you use, it just has to be something unique (not used by any other app yet). https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/custom#namespace

Comment: Thanks, then I believe I should use my application package name, except I'll replace (.) with (_).

Comment: I got it working, thanks to your instructions. But again I'm facing the same problem with FB Share dlg when sharing a FB page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30356298/android-what-is-the-share-dialog-class-in-facebook-sdk-4-x

Comment: @AshrafAlshahawy,@CBroe, I am also facing same issue i.e  To set watching instead of watched for video, Could you please suggest how to fix it.